# Best Linux for a small Web server

Tags: email, php, mysql, nginx, node.js

I'm currently planning my business servers and I would like to know what's the best Linux distro for these needs:

- Nginx + MySQL + PHP 5.4
- Zimbra Collaboration - Open Source
- Node.js w/ Forever

I know it's a objective question but I asked a lot of people and they didn't answer me other thing than "It's your choice"...

I have a 2 CPU, 1GB RAM, 30GB SSD server...

Comment: It's your choice. ;)

Comment: Nice shot :p But nope, I need a specialist advice... I worked with CentOS and Ubuntu but both are heavy on RAM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a distribution that has a low footprint. Debian quickly comes to mind, but I can't see why you wouldn't use ubuntu or centos or even gentoo or arch.

In the end of the day, you should use the distribution **you feel more comfortable with**.

Comment: CentOS: Zimbra not working. Can't tell why. Tried a lot of times...
Ubuntu: Hate it, too heavy on memory.
Fedora: Same as CentOS.

I don't have Gentoo... I'm on DigitalOcean so I can't choose my O/S outside of Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, Arch and CentOS...

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux If I were you I would pick something in between Debian and Arch. But then again, (I can't understand) why was Ubuntu heavy on memory? Were you using the Desktop or the Server version?

Comment: I was using the server version. It took 75% of Ram just for running the base system!